# R: find out identical elements in a list

Tags: r, list

I want to find identical elements from a list. For example, if the list elements are dataframes:

```
List1 <- list(A=data.frame(id=c("LA","WE","SE"),num=c(1,3,2)),
              B=data.frame(id=c("PO","TD","WW"),num=c(8,1,4)),
              C=data.frame(id=c("PO","TD","WW"),num=c(8,1,4)),
              D=data.frame(id=c("SS","FW","MW"),num=c(2,5,1)),
              E=data.frame(id=c("LA","WE","SE"),num=c(1,3,2)),
              G=data.frame(id=c("LA","WE","SE"),num=c(1,3,2)))
```

I want to have the following output:

```
List2 <- list(c("A","E","G"),c("B","C")) 
#i.e., A, E, G are identical. B and C are identical.
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
> unname(split(names(List1), unlist(lapply(List1, toString))))
[[1]]
[1] "A" "E" "G"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "D"
```

Comment: `unlist(lapply(...))` can be replaced by `sapply` if i get it correctly

Comment: Maybe `vapply` would also be faster, i.e. `unname(split(names(List1), vapply(List1, toString, '')))`

Comment: @Maël Yes, that works well too. I was just think if `lapply` + `unlist` might be faster

Comment: @Sotos That's a good idea, I will give a try.

Answer (score 5):

Another option for comparing entire data.frames is to hash them and compare the hashes

```
digests <- sapply(List1, digest::digest)
sets <- split(names(List1), digests)
unname(sets)
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "E" "G"
# [[2]]
# [1] "D"
# [[3]]
# [1] "B" "C"
```

Comment: `digest` looks nice!

Answer (score 2):

In a `tidyverse` framework, you can also `enframe` the list and `group_by` the data.frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
enframe(List1) %>% 
  reframe(name = list(name), .by = value) %>% 
  pull(name)

# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "E" "G"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "B" "C"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "D"
```